# Fix the relation between color and value in `image(.)`

Tags: r, graphics, graph, plot

The two matrices `m1` and `m2` yield to the same `image`.

```
m1 = matrix(1:50, ncol=1)
m2 = matrix(seq(20, 30, length.out = 50), ncol=1)
image(m1, col=terrain.colors(100))
image(m2, col=terrain.colors(100))
```

[image]

That means that the relation between the values of the matrices and the color changes from plot to plot (and it totally makes sense). I'd like to keep this relation constant even if it it decreases the contrast within a single image. One solution is to add a "frame" to my matrices to force image to use the most extreme colors for the same extreme values.

```
min = min(cbind(m1, m2))
max = max(cbind(m1, m2))

m3 = rbind(max, m1 ,min)
image(m3, col=terrain.colors(100))
```

[image]

```
m4 = rbind(max, m2 ,min)
image(m4, col=terrain.colors(100))
```

[image]

It does the trick but it is ugly! I could make a slightly more advanced frame but the presence of the frame on the image will never be really desirable. Is there another solution?

Comment: would this work? `image(m1, col=terrain.colors(50)[m1]);
image(m2, col=terrain.colors(50)[m2])`

Comment: Sweet. That does the trick. I don't fully understand why but it works though. Can you make an answer out of your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to index the color vector by the values in your matrix.
For example:

```
image(m1, col=terrain.colors(50)[m1]); 
image(m2, col=terrain.colors(50)[m2])
```

[image]
`terrain.colors(50)` is a vector of 50 colors. Since `m1` goes from 1 to 50 `terrain.colors(50)[m1]` will be equal to `terrain.colors(50)`, and you will get colors `1` to `50`.

`m2` has decimal numbers from 20 to 30, if you give a decimal number as an index, the largest previous integer is used, so `terrain.colors(50)[m2]` will be a vector of colors between the twentieth and thirtieth colors of `terrain.colors(50)`